# "Ambiguous Class Definition" for classname "I" (Pep8 in Python)

Tags: python, class, pycharm, pep8

**Question:**
Why does PEP8 raise a warning `PEP8: amiguous class definition 'I'` when I try to define a class of name `I`? I could not find that there is any build-in `I`.

[image]

**mwe.py:**

```py
class I:
    pass
```

**Remarks:**

- does not occur for other one-letter names, such as `class E`
- I could not access any other build-in class, object or function `I`
- I didn't succeed with a web-search on this issue, as "`I`" is far from being a unique search term
- observation has been made in `PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)`

Comment: Maybe because `I` looks like `l` and `1`.

Comment: It’s probably because `I` can easily be confused with a capital `L`, lowercase `l`, number `1` or lowercase `i` depending on the font you use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [PEP 8: Names to avoid](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid):

> Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase
>   letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable
>   names.
>
> In some fonts, these characters are indistinguishable from the
>   numerals one and zero. When tempted to use 'l', use 'L' instead.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't know that! :)